# Java does not see JAR file in classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Not a JAVA Newbie!
I keep getting `Error: Could not find or load main class`, this was working last week. My Commandline is

```
java -cp sample.jar com.sample.Myclass
```

sample.jar exists in current folder, Myclass.class has `public static void main(String[] args)` method

I have tried

```
java -cp C:\fullPath\sample.jar com.sample.Myclass
```

When I add option -verbose:class to the command line above I see all jars in jre\lib but not classes from my sample.jar

Why is java ignoring my -cp /-classpath argument?

JAR file is generated as artifact from IntelliJ and Eclipse->Export JAR as well

Comment: This does not, the OP in that question is asking about wildcards in -cp/-classpath, I am not including any wildcards, I am just adding full jarfile name

Comment: What does `jar -tvf sameple.jar` give you ( or whatever command it is to list the contents of the jar file - I don't remember it offhand )

Comment: its jar tf sample.jar, it list all the classed in my jar. I see all the classes there. I even tried to pur all classes in appropriate package folder in the current folder but still no dime! Java does not include current folder as a classpath as well

Comment: Have you tried this: java -cp "C:\fullPath\sample.jar" com.sample.Myclass

Comment: or `java -cp ./sample.jar com.sample.Myclass`

Comment: @DaveH Tried that just now, but no luck